# Please make an "Awesome New Tab Page" widget for Stack Exchange

Tags: support, chrome-extensions, app-request

For Chrome there is this neat extension called [Awesome New Tab Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-new-tab-page/mgmiemnjjchgkmgbeljfocdjjnpjnmcg?hl=en).

Please consider making a Stack Exchange widget for this extension.

Comment: A form of this has already been done: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackoverflow-start-page/